# Unable to get @Input() to work inside the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, input, constructor

I created two components, a parent and a child.

The parent has a member variable called applications:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreService } from 'app/core.service';
import { Application } from 'app/models/application.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-applicationbrowser',
  templateUrl: './applicationbrowser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./applicationbrowser.component.css'],
  providers: [CoreService]
})
export class ApplicationbrowserComponent {
  applications: Application[] = [
    new Application(1, false, "beef"),
    new Application(2, false, "teef"),
    new Application(3, false, "feef")
  ];
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

and uses the child component in its template:

```
<div>
  <app-resourceitem *ngFor="let item of applications" [item]="item"></app-resourceitem>
</div>
```

I assumed that this gets called for each application in my applications variable.

But the child component only ever has an 'undefined' item variable:

```
  @Input()
   item: any;
  constructor() {
    debugger;
    console.log(this.item); //item is always undefined....
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Input` data is available in `ngOnInit`, not the constructor.

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class SomeChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item: any;
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, let me try thi

Comment: Well By sweet baby jesus it worked, i spent two hours messing about in the constructor. Sometimes its the simple things...

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to access **`@Input()`** in the constructor, do it in the ngOnInit life-cycle hook. The constructor has nothing to do with the Angular application life-cycle. Change your code as,

```
@Component({
})
export class SomeChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item: any;
  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.item);
  }
}
```

**[`DEMO WITH STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ev98g?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**